# Formating an integer to two digits

Tags: java, formatting, string-formatting, number-formatting

I am making a game and I'm trying to display the highscore. honestly I don't know what I am doing. I could really use some help.
I want to display the highscore in two digits (e.g. 01, 02, 03 ... 09, 10, 11).

```
private class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView highscore;
    private int hs=00;
    private TextView mtvscore;
    private int Score = 00; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mtvscore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        mtvscore.setText("" + Score);
        highscore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.highscorelabel);
        highscore.setText("" + hs);

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("GAME_DATA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int hs = settings.getInt("HIGH_SCORE", 0);

        if (Score > hs) {
            highscore.setText(Score);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.commit();
        } else {
            highscore.setText(score);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the stack trace from the crash and indicate which line of code the crash is at.

Comment: how do I do that sir @Jon?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html get the stacktrace from logcat

Answer (score 1):

Use String format

```
String twoDigitsHighscore = String.format("%02d", Score);
highscore.setText(twoDigitsHighscore);
```

See the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Remember, this is Java, not Android related only. `String.format` is a Java method, nothing to do with Android.

Android is built using Java.
Try to learn more about what is Java, where does it ends and where Android starts to make your learning process better, as you shouldn't search for "Android two digits integer". You should search for "Java two digits integer".

Comment: thanks sir.how about the shared preferences can you help me with that?

Comment: I don't know what you need, but always look for Android Developer Training website (https://developer.android.com/training) before asking. There are tons of materials there. About SharedPreferences: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#java

Comment: I just need to get the highscore of my game and that's it @Vitor

Comment: regarding to the string format the two digit only display at the first time. so it goes like "00" and then when my score adds it goes back to "1" just one digit

Answer (score 0):

So you need to take your number and format it to a string. It is done automatically for you when you use highScore.setText. Instead you need to use String.format()

```
highscore.setText(String.format("%02d", score));
```

For shared preferences you need.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("GAME_DATA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("HIGH_SOCRE", score);
editor.apply();
```

Comment: thanks sir.how about the shared preferences can you help me with that?

Comment: Looks like you are getting a value from shared preferences... Is something not working? 
I might suggest that you use private static final Strings for the String literals "GAME_DATA" and "HIGH_SCORE" so you do not misspell them wherever you are saving the data.

Comment: Oh you are not saving the data. You need to save the data and apply. Check recent edits.

Comment: Notice I used apply instead of commit. You are on the main thread apply is async.

Comment: but regardin to the string format the two digit only display at the first time. so it goes like "00" and then when my score adds it goes back to "1" just one digit

Comment: You are going to need to give more information than that. Here is code using %02d to format ints and spit them out it clearly works. jdoodle.com/a/og7 So it is difficult to tell where you are running into issues. Looks like you added something and your app is crashing. You need to be more specific. Post your errors and any code related to them.